# Show SINGLE RECORD with newest expiration date

Tags: php, if-statement, record

I am using a FFDB database (flat File Database).

This script works as long as $vinc field has the same value, but I have 5 different types of $vinc values R1, R2, R3, R4, R5 - if I add new record where $vinc is not R1, a blank page appears instead.

```
  <?php

     function getbyfunction($selectfn, $orderby = NULL, $includeindex = false)
     {
        if (!$this->isopen)
        {
           user_error("Database not open.", E_USER_ERROR);
           return false;
        }

        // If there are no records, return
        if ($this->records == 0)
           return array();

        if (!$this->lock_read())
           return false;

        // Read the index
        $index = $this->read_index();

        // Read each record and add it to an array
        $rcount = 0;
        foreach($index as $offset)
        {
           // Read the record
           list($record, $rsize) = $this->read_record($this->data_fp, $offset);

           // Add it to the result if the $selectfn OK's it
           if ($selectfn($record) == true)
           {
              // Add the index field if required
              if ($includeindex)
                 $record[FFDB_IFIELD] = $rcount;

              $result[] = $record;
           }

           ++$rcount;
        }

        $this->unlock();

        // Re-order as required
        if ($orderby !== NULL)
           return $this->order_by($result, $orderby);
        else
           return $result;
  }


  function returnRec($item){
           if($item)
            return true;
  }

  $db = new FFDB();
  if (!$db->open("foo"))
  {
     $schema = array(
        array("key", FFDB_INT, "key"),
        array("status", FFDB_STRING),
        array("vinc", FFDB_STRING),
        array("month", FFDB_STRING),
        array("day", FFDB_INT),
        array("year", FFDB_INT)
    );
       // Try and create it...
     if (!$db->create("foo", $schema))
     {
        echo "Error creating database\n";
        return;
     }
  }

  $result = $db->getbyfunction("returnRec", "vinc");
       show_rec(end($result));

  function show_rec($record){
     $number = $record["key"];
     $Rvinc = $record["vinc"];
     $Rstatus = $record["status"];
     $Rday = $record["day"];
     $Rmonth = $record["month"];
     $Ryear = $record["year"];

  $tday = getdate();
  $current_year = $tday['year'];
  $current_month = $tday['month'];

  if (($status == ON) && ($vinc == R1) && ($month >= $current_month) && ($year ==                   current_year)){

  echo "myrecord $vinc $status $day $month $year";

  }
  ?>
```

Any help?!

Thanks

---

Yegge, using show_rec($result[0]); it shows 1 record but instead the most recent expiration date is showing the latest expiration date:

i.e.:
1 record expire 08/01/2011
2 record expire 11/01/2011

show_rec($result[0]); is showing the record with expiration date 11/01/2011 instead of 08/01/2011

---

Yegge

show_rec(end($result)); worked as long as $vinc == R1 only, if adding another record where vinc is not R1 then shows a blank page, any ideas?

Comment: Well, what kind of database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

     function getbyfunction($selectfn, $orderby = NULL, $includeindex = false)
     {
        if (!$this->isopen)
        {
           user_error("Database not open.", E_USER_ERROR);
           return false;
        }

        // If there are no records, return
        if ($this->records == 0)
           return array();

        if (!$this->lock_read())
           return false;

        // Read the index
        $index = $this->read_index();

        // Read each record and add it to an array
        $rcount = 0;
        foreach($index as $offset)
        {
           // Read the record
           list($record, $rsize) = $this->read_record($this->data_fp, $offset);

           // Add it to the result if the $selectfn OK's it
           if ($selectfn($record) == true)
           {
              // Add the index field if required
              if ($includeindex)
                 $record[FFDB_IFIELD] = $rcount;

              $result[] = $record;
           }

           ++$rcount;
        }

        $this->unlock();

        // Re-order as required
        if ($orderby !== NULL)
           return $this->order_by($result, $orderby);
        else
           return $result;
  }


  function returnRec($item){
           if($item)
            return true;
  }

  $db = new FFDB();
  if (!$db->open("foo"))
  {
     $schema = array(
        array("key", FFDB_INT, "key"),
        array("status", FFDB_STRING),
        array("vinc", FFDB_STRING),
        array("month", FFDB_STRING),
        array("day", FFDB_INT),
        array("year", FFDB_INT)
    );
       // Try and create it...
     if (!$db->create("foo", $schema))
     {
        echo "Error creating database\n";
        return;
     }
  }

  $result = $db->getbyfunction("returnRec", "vinc");
  foreach($result as $item) {show_rec($item);break;}

  function show_rec($record){
     $number = $record["key"];
     $Rvinc = $record["vinc"];
     $Rstatus = $record["status"];
     $Rday = $record["day"];
     $Rmonth = $record["month"];
     $Ryear = $record["year"];

      $tday = getdate();
  $current_year = $tday['year'];
  $current_month = $tday['month'];

  if (($status == ON) && ($vinc == R1) && ($month >= $current_month) && ($year ==                   current_year)){

  echo "myrecord $vinc $status $day $month $year";

  }
  ?>
```

i think you need to use break in loop, like above.

Answer (score 0):

```
select product, expirationdate from your_table

where expirationdate > {current_date} order by expirationdate ASC limit 1
```

{current_date} is variable that should be passed from php or you can use mysql function instead

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your code correctly, instead of

```
foreach($result as $item) {show_rec($item);break;}
//use
show_rec($result[0]); //only show the very first item in the result array
```

Edit: Then use this:

```
show_rec(end($result));
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

I just want to make sure to post the solution:

```
$result = $db->getall(lp_month,lp_year);
$i = 0;
foreach ($result as $row){
   print_r (show_record($row));
if ($i >= 1) 
 break;
$i++;
}
```

Not a lot different from what I initially had, but **print_r** instead of **echo** did the trick:

```
   print_r (show_record($row));
```

Thanks